# Browserify + Gulp + Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, gulp, browserify

I'm creating a boilerplate project for working with the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/) with the following file structure while following [this handy guide](http://viget.com/extend/gulp-browserify-starter-faq):

```
.
├── build
|   ├── js
|      └── bundle.js
|   ├── stylesheets
|      ├── main.css
|      └── main.min.css
|   └── index.html
├── node_modules
|   └── [gulp, gulp-watch, etc...]
├── src
|   ├── js
|       └── main.js
├── sass
|   ├── _main_settings.scss [for overriding default Foundation settings]
|   └── main.scss
├── templates
|   └── index.jade
├── bower.json
├── gulpfile.js
└── package.json
```

Should I `bower install foundation` in the root folder, or would it make more sense to put it inside the `src` folder? I've gotten the scss working by following [this guide](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/oct/21/ultimate-front-end-development-setup/), however I'm not sure how to use browserify to bundle up the foundation js so that I can just import one neat compiled file in `index.html`. In addition, I'd like to import `modernizr` separately, in the head section rather than at the end of the body.

If it helps, here is my [gulpfile](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpdvYy?editors=001) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deciding to use npm to install foundation rather than bower, however either way I left `bower_components` / `node_modules` in the `root` folder rather than `build`.

`browserify-shim` is necessary to get browserify to play nice with Foundation, as was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111777/browserify-with-zurb-foundation-framework).

I ended up making a Yeoman generator to scaffold out a project with Foundation, Gulp and Browserify, feel free to check it out: https://github.com/dougmacklin/generator-foundation-browserify